# Sending SMS using clickatell in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms, sms-gateway, clickatell

I have tried this code from their site

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
// Add a user agent header in case the requested URI contains a query.
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
client.QueryString.Add("user", "xxxx");
client.QueryString.Add("password", "xxxx");
client.QueryString.Add("api_id", "xxxx");
client.QueryString.Add("to", "xxxx");
client.QueryString.Add("text", "This is an example message");
string baseurl = "http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg";
Stream data = client.OpenRead(baseurl);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
data.Close();
reader.Close();
return s;
```

I am getting an Proxy authentication failure in

```
string baseurl ="http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg";
```

Can anyone help me out??

Comment: What is the failure message ?

Comment: The error message is : The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are behind a proxy and your web client needs to authenticate. Try the following code:

```
string userName = "<user name>";
string password = "<password>";
ICredentials creds = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
client.Credentials = creds;
```